# Query Posts dont work in Wordpress shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Alright now, I have tried A LOT of shortcode snippets to display 3 recent posts as a shortcode in my post (not page).

Like:

```
function posts_shortcode() {
$the_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 3));

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

}

add_shortcode('posts', 'posts_shortcode');
```

and

```
function posts_shortcode() { // From Smashingmagazine
query_posts(array('orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' , 'showposts' => 3));
   if (have_posts()) :
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
         $return_string = '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
      endwhile;
   endif;
   wp_reset_query();
   return $return_string;
}

function register_shortcodes(){
   add_shortcode('posts', 'posts_shortcode'); 
}
```

and even

```
function wptuts_recentpost($atts, $content=null){ // From WP Tuts+

    $getpost = get_posts( array('number' => 1) );

    $getpost = $getpost[0];

    $return = $getpost->post_title . "<br />" . $getpost->post_excerpt . "…";

    $return .= "<br /><a href='" . get_permalink($getpost->ID) . "'><em>read more →</em></a>";

    return $return;

}
add_shortcode('newestpost', 'wptuts_recentpost');
```

All of these don't seem to work. I quess it has something to do with the loop or something. If I remove the loop and only do something like

```
return 'hey there';
```

in the function(), then it works just fine.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** 
With the following shortcode:

```
function posts_shortcode() { // From Smashingmagazine
query_posts($args);
   if (have_posts()) :
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        $return_string = '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
      endwhile;
   endif;
   wp_reset_query();
   return $return_string;

}

add_shortcode('posts', 'posts_shortcode');
```

I managed to get some result, but it now displays the text Home with the link to my frontpage. First of all, I don't see why.. And second, when I replace $args with 'posts_per_page=5', it's gone again. I realy think there's something wrong with the loop for some reason..

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the first one. You should never echo anything inside a shortcode function.

The last one will only print one post. Besides, I think it should be array('numberposts' => 1) , not array('number' => 1).

The second one should work, but you're wrapping add_shortcode in a function so you need to call that at some point. For example, add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes' ); or put add_shortcode right into functions.php.

Comment: Hi Calle, I've tried your suggestions but they don't work. The second one you were referring to neither. I did, however, delete the loop, and just do $return_string = 'hello', that does work. But whenever I try to loop through posts, it's just blank.

Comment: Your edited piece of code is how I wanted it, assuming $args is the same array used before. There also appears to be a typo, try changing $return_string = '... to $return_string .= '...

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me

```
add_shortcode( 'objectx-pages-list', 'objectx_pages_list_func' );
function objectx_pages_list_func( $atts ) {
global $post;
ob_start();
extract( shortcode_atts( array('ids' => '1186'), $atts ) );
$id_array = explode(',', $ids); 
$pages_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post__in' => $id_array,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'title',
) );
if ( $pages_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
<div class="carousel-wrapper">
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme carousel-1" id="carousel-rooms">
<?php while ( $pages_query->have_posts() ) : $pages_query->the_post();
$featured_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
?>
<div <?php post_class('item'); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="img-rooms">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <img class="img-responsive wp-post-image" src="<?php echo $featured_image; ?>"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="detail-rooms">
            <h2 class="title-room "><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php $myvariable_pages = ob_get_clean();
wp_reset_postdata();
return $myvariable_pages;
    }
}
```

**Shortcode**

```
[objectx-pages-list id="15,16,17"]
```